# How to restrict a user to pick only JPG images from the gallery?

Tags: android, android-gallery, android-selector

In my application I have an option which allows a user to pick an image from gallery and use it in the application. However I would want to restrict the user to select only images with `.jpg` extension. How do I achieve that?

So far I've tried the following, but each type of image is at the disposal with this approach:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
intent.setType("image/*");
startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
```

Comment: Have you tried "image/jpeg"?

Comment: Right away I will try it.

Comment: Not working, it shows videos too if I try ("image/jpg");

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**1.** You can use

```
intent.setType("image/jpeg");
```

or

```
intent.setType("image/jpg");
```

**2.** Or you can use the onActivityResult to check the file using :

```
filePath.endsWith(".jpg")
```

if the **files are of kind .jpg or .jpeg then only implement** your **logic else Toast that the file should be in .jpg format.**

Comment: I tried both as stated above by @dtmilano but its not working, even videos on the gallery are shown. I will give filePath.endsWith(".jpg); option a try now.

Comment: how to set multiple types here. Like jpeg, png, mp4 and other ?